# how to match www urls with regular expressions

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-config

I have found this bit of web.config code for checking the url to see if its missing the www. if it is then it redirects the user to the www. url

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

however i need to do the opposite and i have been hacking around with it (im not very good with regular expressions, no matter how much i try) to try and get it to see if the url has www then redirect it to the non www

reason being is i have a subdomain

trade.words.co.uk
but i want to make sure they dont go to www.trade.words.co.uk

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: So that if someone types www.trade.words.co.uk they should be redirected to trade.words.co.uk?

Comment: Note : if you have trouble dealing with regular expression, consider using this pretty nice tool http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: thanks for your help marcus, however i get an 'This web page has a redirect loop' error with this

Comment: Oh sorry, try now. I've made an update. Hehe, I managed to slip in that if it wasn't www it still should be redirected

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need the opposite web.config rule using an extended regular expression to match proper url like the following :

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([\w-]+://?|www[.])([^\s]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hi Sebastian, thanks for this, there seems to be an error when i add this to the web.config. its doesnt like the < bracket in the regular expression, conflicting with the xml i guess...

Comment: If you have trouble you can simplify the regular expression with ([\w-]+://?|www[.])([^\s]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))) .. I'll update my post accordingly